# Minimize the sum of $r$-largest entries with constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I was being stuck by this optimization problem for a long time. My optimization problem is about to minimize the sum of the largest $r$ entries of a vector.
$$
min_x \sum_{l=1}^r(Ax)_{[l]}~~s.t. Bx\le b
$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the decision variable, and $(\cdot)_{[l]}$ is the $l$-th largest componet of $(\cdot)$.

The objective is convex and so do the constraints (see [Example 3.14 on page 87 of "Convex Optimization" by Prof. Boyd](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)). Furthermore, this problem can be transformed into the following linear programming
$$
\begin{aligned}
min_{x,z}~z\\
s.t.~ Bx\le b\\
QAx\le r1
\end{aligned}
$$
where $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\r\end{array}\right)\times n}$ is the combination matrix which has $r$ entries with 1 and $(n-r)$ entries with 0. The matrix $Q$ actually indicates all combination of $r$ of $Ax$'s entries' sum.

This transformation seems to be great, and the transformed problem can be solved using the interior point method. However, there are more than $\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\r\end{array}\right)$ inequality constraints, which makes it hard to solve.

My question is how can we solve this problem more efficiently. I searched online and find that the "sub-gradient method" seems to work. However, this problem may converge rather slow.
Any suggestions and clues are welcomed. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to talk about some naive enumerative representation of sum-of-k-largest. You can model that much more efficiently.

The sum of the $k$ largest values of $Ax\in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented, when used in a convexity preserving setting, using a scalar $t$ by introducing a scalar $s$ and vector $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with

$$
t\geq ks + \sum_{i=1}^n z_i,~z\geq 0,~ z  +s \geq Ax
$$

I do not have a reference in my head at the moment, although I suspect you can find it in the book you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did not realize that k-largest-sum can be transformed in such efficient way. I checked the "convex optimization" book and did not find this transform though... First, I think it would be $z+s\mathbf{1}\ge Ax$ right? Next, could you give me a little more hint on this transformation? Like some intuitions about $z$, $s$, and $t$.

Comment: Yes, if you want to add 1 for notational clarity that is correct (typically assumed that vector + scalar simply means that). Here is a derivation https://www.tau.ac.il/~atamir/min_03.pdf

Comment: Really thanks for your help. I have checked the paper, and this transformation is definitely brilliant! I still want to go further: what if I have some different weights for the sum of $r$ largest components. That is, the objective becomes $\sum_{l=1}^{r} w(l)\cdot (Ax)_{[l]}$ where all $w(l)$ are positive numbers. I also tried the similar idea in the paper to construct some function to represent the objective function. But it seems like not working well.

Comment: With non-increasing weights, it is still LP-representable. Don't remember any reference directly, but here is the implementation in YALMIP https://github.com/yalmip/YALMIP/blob/develop/operators/sumk_generator.m. For arbitrary weights, it is not a convex problem and much much harder.

Comment: That's true. Forget the non-convex issue. Really thanks for your help!